# Getting the next upcoming date of a pool of date-objects

Tags: javascript, html

I have to show the next event on my website. No database available.
  My idea: To create a javascript array with Date-Objects and then I need a function to say: Give me the next upcoming date of my created DateObject-Array.
  How can I do that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Why not just search through the array (assuming it's sorted) and just call the array element after that? Also, why can't you use a database?

Comment: I have a list of events next days.
 And I need a script to show the next upcoming event.
 When I create a array with the Dates how my website know tomorrow what the next event is ?

Comment: Do you have an event every day? Is your array sorted? Does your array contain previous events or are they removed? How are the array elements structured?

Comment: Yes it's sorted. But old entries will be not removed. How my website could know which index is the current?

Answer (score 0):

Using this Binary Search function I found after a simple search and shamelessly copied from Code Review, you can pass it the events array and tomorrow's date (`Date(today.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))`).

```
function binarySearch(arr, find) 
{
  var low = 0, high = arr.length - 1, i, comparison;
  while (low <= high) 
  {
    i = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (arr[i] < find) 
    { 
       low = i + 1;
    }
    if (arr[i] > find)
    { 
       high = i - 1; 
    }
    return i;
  }
  return null;
}

var currentEvent = binarySearch(eventsArray, Date(today.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));

//code to display eventsArray[currentEvent] here
```